# Evaluating functions out of expressions stored in list

Tags: functions, function-construction, syntax

I have a method that takes an integer $n$ and returns a list of variables `vars = {x1,...,xn}` and down the line a list of expressions in $x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}$ is created:
$$\text{exps} = \lbrace \text{expression } 1,\cdots, \text{expression } n \rbrace.$$
Now, I want to make a new list consisting of each expression evaluated at some point in $n$-tuple. In other words, for some point `a = {a1,...,an}`, I would like
$$ \text{final} = \lbrace \text{expression } 1 |_{a}, \cdots, \text{expression } n|_{a} \rbrace. $$
I have tried

```
 final = {};
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[vars], i++,
     f[vars[[i]]_] := exps[[i]];
     AppendTo[final, f[ai]];
 ]
 final
```

but I don't think Mathematica likes me using `f[vars[[i]]_]` and returns an error stating that "Tag Function... is Protected." My idea seems not very robust at best. How would I go about interpreting this list of expressions as a list of functions, evaluating at my desired point, and creating a new list with the evaluated expressions?

Comment: can you post an example of  what, say, `expression1` in `exps` looks like?

Comment: maybe `exps /. Thread[vars -> a]`?

Comment: `Through[{e1, e2, e3} @@ {a1, a2, a3, a4}]`?

Comment: @kglr An example of `expressions1` would be something like `x1+2(x2+x3)`. I don't have Mathematica handy right now, so I'll give the suggestions a try tomorrow. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vars = Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString @ #] &, 5];
aa = Array[Symbol["a" <> ToString @ #] &, 5];

SeedRandom[1];
exps = vars.RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}];
exps  // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize\{\text{x1}+\text{x3}+\text{x4},4 \text{x1}+8 \text{x2}+8 \text{x3}+3
>    \text{x4}+2 \text{x5},6 \text{x2}+5 \text{x3}+2 \text{x4}+6
>    \text{x5},7 \text{x1}+\text{x3}+\text{x4}+4 \text{x5},4
>    \text{x2}+\text{x3}+6 \text{x4}+5 \text{x5}\}$

You can use `ReplaceAll` to replace `vars` in `exps` with `aa` :

```
newexps = exps /. Thread[vars -> aa];
newexps  // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize\{\text{a1}+\text{a3}+\text{a4},4 \text{a1}+8 \text{a2}+8 \text{a3}+3
>    \text{a4}+2 \text{a5},6 \text{a2}+5 \text{a3}+2 \text{a4}+6
>    \text{a5},7 \text{a1}+\text{a3}+\text{a4}+4 \text{a5},4
>    \text{a2}+\text{a3}+6 \text{a4}+5 \text{a5}\}$

Alternatively, you can make `exps` into a function of `vars` and use it on `aa`:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[Pattern[#, _] & /@ vars] := Evaluate[exps]
foo @ aa // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize\{\text{a1}+\text{a3}+\text{a4},4 \text{a1}+8 \text{a2}+8 \text{a3}+3
>    \text{a4}+2 \text{a5},6 \text{a2}+5 \text{a3}+2 \text{a4}+6
>    \text{a5},7 \text{a1}+\text{a3}+\text{a4}+4 \text{a5},4
>    \text{a2}+\text{a3}+6 \text{a4}+5 \text{a5}\}$

Or, make `exps` into a pure function `bar` that can be `Apply`ed to `aa`:

```
bar = Function[Evaluate[exps /. Thread[vars -> Slot /@ Range[Length@vars]]]];
bar @@ aa // TeXForm
```

> same result as above

Comment: Yet again you provided a great, comprehensive answer! Thanks, works well!

Comment: @Dan, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.